# Getting 502 bad gateway on google cloud

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I own a n1-highcpu-16 (16 vCPUs, 14.4 GB memory). I have that with a Bitnami NGINX setup.

When I have about 400-600 people on site it gives 502 bad gateway sometimes. I am running bots with that, so it tends to make big errors for me. It happens when site receives about 50-100 requests to the PHP file which does a one SQL connection.
After that, on my site appears a 502 bad gateway error.

Is there any solution how to fix that?

My PHP settings:

```
pm=static

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI. The below defaults are based on a server without much resources. Don't
; forget to tweak pm.* to fit your needs.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children=50

; The number of child processes created on startup.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers=5

; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.min_spare_servers=5

; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.max_spare_servers=30

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 5000
```

Comment: An HTTP error like a 502 is a symptom which is telling you to do something like "check your application logs". A 502 specifically means something is wrong with a connection to an upstream server, and since you mention that you using a single SQL connection to handle all of your request traffic, my guess is that it would have something to do with that.

Comment: I just noticed this was posted a month ago, not today, so please let us know if you ever found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an issue with the SQL connection? Because your `pm.max_children` is set to `50`, if all 50 threads are in use, a **502 Bad Gateway** error will be thrown. You should try spinning up additional servers to handle more requests.

Alternatively, try raising and lowering `pm.max_children` and see if this affects the numbers, and helps draw a conclusion.